# MATLAB: extract part of a string

Tags: string, matlab

I want to extract a part of a string (in my case filename) that looks like this

```
filename = '12345_name_IV_a12.dat'
```

I am interested in the part between `'_IV_'` (that appears in all files) and `'.dat'`. Thus, the answer should look like that

```
a    
12
```

Possible? `12345` and `'name'` might change in length. The number (`12`) can also be only one digit long.

Comment: Of course it's possible, what have you tried so far? To get going, take a look at [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) and [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). You can do the job using only the latter, but the former might be useful if you want to strip a preceding path as well.

Comment: I tried to play with regexp but had some problems getting only the part between _IV_ and .dat

Comment: is the letter before the sequence of digits at the end always a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
parts=strsplit(filename, {'_IV_', '.dat'});
result=parts{2};
```

If you want to split the result in numerals and characters you can use `regexp` as stated in the comments:

```
character = result(regexp(result,'\D'));
numeral = result(regexp(result,'\d'));
```

In this case `character` contains `a`, and `numeral` the string `12`.

Comment: teststr = '12345_filename_IV_a12.dat'
[important unimportant] = strsplit(teststr, {'_IV_', '.dat'})
coordinates = important(2)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
regexp('12345_name_IV_a12.dat', '.*_IV_(\D*)(\d*)\.dat$', 'tokens', 'once')
```

I'll explain the pattern `'.*_IV_(\D*)(\d*)\.dat$'` a bit.  I worked backwards from the end of the filename.  The `$` marks the end of the string.  Then I match the file extension, two tokens (demarcated with parentheses), and `_IV_`.

The `'tokens'` flag causes it to return the two tokens, and the `'once'` flag stops it from wrapping the result in an extra cell array.

I think this expression is pretty unambiguous and will always give you the right result.  I hope it solves your problem.